# WinRT application accessing external LAN via Cisco VPN

Tags: c#, vpn, cisco, windows-rt

I'm developing a WinRT application. Said application will use a corporate LAN in the end to connect to available services. I suspect things will work smoothly then.

However, I'm having a bit of an issue during development.

Since I'm not on-site where the services are being developed (and where the test services have been deployed) I've been given VPN access using the Cisco Systems VPN client.

Note, that I can access the services using a browser, so I know the connection is working fine.

My issue is that the WindowsRT application doesn't seem to play nice with the VPN connection, and I get the following error when attempting to access the services:

> Could not connect to net.tcp://[ServiceIp]/[ServicePath].
>
> The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:00.0463816.
>
> TCP error code 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
> forbidden by its access permissions [ServiceIp].

AFAIK the above error is thrown when a WinRT application doesn't have the required permission (for example, to access LAN or WAN). However, out of desperation, I've tried ticking ALL the requested capabilities boxes in the package configuration, but I'd still get the same error.

Furthermore we've been given a local version of the services, and in our own LAN the application CAN connect.

Note: I still want to connect to the development machine over the VPN, because that's where all the test data is (our own machine has mock data - it was initially useful, but at this stage we need to do more specific tests).

So it seems like WinRT is throwing a hissy-fit when it's forced to use the Cisco VPN... not that I blame it - I don't like that VPN myself! :P

Still, I'd like to be able to connect to the test services. Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Chances are this is an application permissions issue - a quick search on the error revealed the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244875/wcf-client-tcp-error-10013-while-connecting-only-if-connection-to-windows-dc-i

Comment: @Chris Did you read the whole question, or just the exception? I explicitly wrote that I tried giving my application ALL the permissions possible, but I would still get the same exception when attempting to connect to the server behind that Cisco VPN.

Comment: Sorry, missed just that paragraph.  How are you doing the testing? On localhost, or an actual WinRT device or simulator?

Comment: @Chris Mostly localhost. I do have an actual WinRT device as well for final testing, but when I can't connect from my machine I don't see why the device should be able to connect either. Also note, I can deploy a release build onto my localhost machine and run it straight from Windows 8 with the same results.

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark, perhaps the WinRT app sandboxing is having an effect.  Your VPN is most likely a standard windows app, and the sandboxed WinRT app may not have access to the VPN connection.  Recently I noticed a new Cisco VPN for my Win8 phone (finally!), so perhaps there is one from the app store for WinRT.  As I said, a shot in the dark - but hopefully it leads somewhere.

Comment: I can check @Chris, but as far as I can tell the Cisco app creates a network adapter on install and uses that. It's just that said adapter seems to have a strange configuration, and is handled via the client application. Note that the exception message seems to suggest that the connection could be established, but some part of WinRT security terminates it.